# Firestore "GreaterThanOrEqualTo" and "LessThanOrEqualTo" queries gives only initial values in Recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I am working on a project that has value in the Firestore database i.e."ServiceCost". It is of String Type.
I need to filter my Recyclerview items for the "ServiceCost" data, for that, I am using Firestore Queries. First do check the database snapshot.
[image]

I have used a range seekbar that selects range, with that i had to filter the recyclerview. But that didn't work.
Now for testing i have only created a query range, that is below:

```
loaddataforrange(String sValue, String eValue) {
    Query query1 = collectionReference.where(Filter.and(
                Filter.equalTo("garageZone", zoneName),
                Filter.or(Filter.greaterThanOrEqualTo("ServiceCost", sValue),
                        Filter.lessThanOrEqualTo("ServiceCost", eValue))
        ));
}
```

In which i am passing the min and max value from range seekbar. Suppose:

```
loaddataforrange("500", "5000");
```

But it is only giving me items which have ServiceCost 500 and 5000, not in between items.
What to do now? What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing the `ServiceCost` as a string value, which means that the ordering/filtering on its values will happen on [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order). And in lexicographical order, a value of `"1000"` does not fall between `"500"` and `"5000"`.

There is no way to reliably filter the string values you have. To allow the use-case, store numerical values as actual numbers and filter on them with numerical values too.

Comment: Okay, if I store values in number, will it work?

Comment: But in the Filter.greaterthanorequalto the arguments should be passed as a string.

Comment: First off: does the first paragraph of my answer make sense, and does it explain why you're getting the results you said? --- Second: the `value` parameter is declared as an `Object` not as a `String`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Filter#greaterThanOrEqualTo(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)

Comment: Yes I understood the first paragraph

Comment: Do I need to add the value into an integer while uploading data into firestore?

Comment: You can do it manually for testing, but you'll probably want to fix the code that writes to the database after that.

Comment: thanks, it worked. I have accepted your answer. thanks a lot again for clearing up the confusion.

Comment: i have changed the type from string to int, and it worked.